# Unable to set author and title using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am able to get and set the author and title name but unable to see it in output file. When i see details by clicking right and of my output file , it has old author and title name. please help me..

I am using poi apache api for excel files.

Following is the sample of my code :

```
public void processPOIFSReaderEvent(POIFSReaderEvent event)
{
   SummaryInformation si = null;       
   si = (SummaryInformation) PropertySetFactory.create(event.getStream());    
   si.setTitle(title);
   si.setAuthor("Author Name");
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need to write back to stream your changes.

Check example [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/poi/hpsf/examples/ModifyDocumentSummaryInformation.java.html)

Comment: Thanks viny i got it, from your example...i am able to set all properties now

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**HSSF:**

```java
SummaryInformation summaryInfo = workbook.getSummaryInformation();
summaryInfo.setAuthor(author);
```

**XSSF:**

```java
POIXMLProperties xmlProps = workbook.getProperties();    
POIXMLProperties.CoreProperties coreProps = xmlProps.getCoreProperties();    
coreProps.setCreator(author);
```

Comment: Hi,
I tried this but it shows cast it, when i casted it is showing error on getSummaryInformation()

:(

SummaryInformation summaryInfo = ((Object) workbook).getSummaryInformation(); 
          summaryInfo.setAuthor("Author");

Comment: @MandeepSingh Whay are you casting it to object? getSummaryInformation returns the object SummaryInformation. I dont think you really need to cast. Make sure your imports are correct.